# Bash function with IF statement

Tags: bash

Is there a way to have a function which will take a -y flag and answer yes to all the questions instead of the user doing Y to each question, After specifying what database to use ?

when running script.sh I would like to run it as ./script.sh -y which will ask me what database to use and then do YES to all the questions:

```sh
#Database selection
echo "Enter the database name: "
read databasename


#Questions

read -r -p "Do you want to anonymise Customer Forename/Surname ? [y/N] " response1
if  [[ $1 = "-y" ]] || [[ "$response1" =~ ^([yY][eE][sS]|[yY])$ ]]
then
    pv forenamesurname.sql | mysql "$databasename"
echo  "Anonym OK"
else
    echo "Anonym not OK"
fi


    exit
```

Comment: you can use [positional parameters](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/How_to_use_positional_parameters) to achieve that.

Comment: This will use use y as the $databasename so it will just prompt with "the database does not exist"  and I would like it to have it as a flag so running a script like that: ./script.sh -y or ./script.sh -n

Comment: _I would like it to have it as a flag_ : this is where you can use the positional parameters like `$1` and `$2` to check if the 1st and 2nd parameters are `-y` and `-n` and then apply the `if` conditions in your code block at the right place.

Comment: Side note: There is no function in your script - the title of your question is a bit misleading in this respect. Aside from this, I think the main issue is a design problem: You are expecting the database name coming from stdin (i.e. via a prompt), and the flag as a parameter; but if you **want** to invoke your script with `-y` or `-n` as a parameter, you have to fetch this argument of course from within your script (it is stored on `$1`).

Comment: @user1934428 Hi, thanks for the explanation, would you be able to help wit this as I am not quite sure how to do it ? 
I was trying to do something like that: if [[ $1 = "-y" ]] || [[ "$response1" =~ ^([yY][eE][sS]|[yY])$ ]]
but I guess the script wouldn't know what the $1 is if it's not in the script ??
sorry if I have explained it wrong

Comment: Don't put code in a comment. It is nearly unreadable. Put it into your script. Also, you are posting too much. Post a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work correctly, because you are always execute the `read`, even if a paramter is supplied.

I would eader replace the `read` statement completely by

```
response1=${1:--n} # Sets response1 to, i.e., -y
response1=${response1:1:1} # Sets response1 to just y
```

which sets it to the first parameter, respectively to `-n` if no parameter has been passed. Alternatively, you could do a

```
if [[ -n ${1:-} ]] # Do we have a parameter?
then
  response=${1:1:1}
else
  read -r -p "Do you want to anonymise Customer Forename/Surname ? [y/N] " response1
fi
```

which is nearly the same, but asks explicitly for y/n, if no parameter has been supplied.